# bash does not recognize if conditions within a for loop for each element for an array of strings

Tags: bash, shell-script

### Goal

I am using `whiptail` to let the user insert passwords to files which are used in conjunction with `envsubst` for some template files.

#### `whiptail` checklist

in order to render stuff in `whiptail` I use the following:

```bash
declare -A availableServices=(
    [grafana]="Grafana Dashboard"
    [influxdb]="InfluxDB v1.x TSDB"
    [node-red]="Node-RED Flow UI"
    [portainer]="Portainer Container Mgmt"
)

# Render TUI
function askGenerateCredential() {
    local message="Set Password for particular Service\n
                Press <SPACEBAR> to Select \n
                Press <Enter> to Skip
                "
    local arglist=()
    
    # Generate a String for Whiptail Checkboxes
     # FORMAT: "<INDEX> <DESCRIPTION> <OFF>"
    for index in "${!availableServices[@]}";
    do
        # Default all Services are NOT-Selected (OFF)
        arglist+=("$index" "${availableServices[$index]}" "OFF")
    done
    SELECTED_SERVICES+=$($WHIPTAIL --title "Available Services within Populo" \
                --notags --separate-output \
                --ok-button Next \
                --nocancel \
                --checklist "$message" $LINES $COLUMNS $(( LINES - 12 )) \
                -- "${arglist[@]}" \
                3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
}
```

the `SELECTED_SERVICES` is an array declared as

```bash
declare -a SELECTED_SERVICES=()
```

The rendering works well, however I have a specific `if else` condition in my script that is unable to execute specific commands based on the selected service in the array above.

```bash
askGenerateCredential
if [ -z "$SELECTED_SERVICES" ]; then
    echo "No Services were selected. Exiting..."
    exit 1
else
    for service in "${SELECTED_SERVICES}";
    do
        if [ "$service" == "influxdb" ]; then
            echo "Setting Credentials for InfluxDB"
            setInfluxDBCredentials
        elif [ "$service" == "grafana" ]; then
            echo "Setting Credentials for Grafana"
            setGrafanaCredentials
        elif [ "$service" == "node-red" ]; then
            echo "Setting Credentials for node-RED"
            setNodeRedCredentials
        elif [ "$service" == "portainer" ]; then
            echo "Setting Credential for Portainer"
            setPortainerCredentials
        fi
    done
fi
```

Upon adding the above block, my script exits with `0` code when I select multiple values via `whiptail` UI. On the contrary, when I only select one value in the UI, the respective function is called.

What am I doing wrong here? I wish that depending on the `service` variable, the respective function is called and not exit the script.

### Code

```bash
#!/bin/env bash

WHIPTAIL=$(which whiptail)

if [ -z $WHIPTAIL ]
then
    echo "This script requires whiptail to render the TUI."
    exit 1
fi

declare -a SELECTED_SERVICES=()

LINES=$(tput lines)
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)


declare -A availableServices=(
    [grafana]="Grafana Dashboard"
    [influxdb]="InfluxDB v1.x TSDB"
    [node-red]="Node-RED Flow UI"
    [portainer]="Portainer Container Mgmt"
)

function askGenerateCredential() {
    local message="Set Password for particular Service\n
                Press <SPACEBAR> to Select \n
                Press <Enter> to Skip
                "
    local arglist=()
    
    # Generate a String for Whiptail Checkboxes
     # FORMAT: "<INDEX> <DESCRIPTION> <OFF>"
    for index in "${!availableServices[@]}";
    do
        # Default all Services are NOT-Selected (OFF)
        arglist+=("$index" "${availableServices[$index]}" "OFF")
    done
    SELECTED_SERVICES+=$($WHIPTAIL --title "Available Services within Populo" \
                --notags --separate-output \
                --ok-button Next \
                --nocancel \
                --checklist "$message" $LINES $COLUMNS $(( LINES - 12 )) \
                -- "${arglist[@]}" \
                3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
}

function setInfluxDBCredential() {
    echo "set admin password env var for influxdb"
}

function setGrafanaCredential() {
    echo "set admin password env var for grafana"
}

function setNodeRedCredential() {
    echo "set admin password env var for node-REd"
}

function setPortainerCredential() {
    echo "set password file for portainer"
}

askGenerateCredential
if [ -z "$SELECTED_SERVICES" ]; then
    echo "No Services were selected. Exiting..."
    exit 1
else
    for service in "${SELECTED_SERVICES}";
    do
        if [ "$service" == "influxdb" ]; then
            echo "Setting Credentials for InfluxDB"
            setInfluxDBCredentials
        elif [ "$service" == "grafana" ]; then
            echo "Setting Credentials for Grafana"
            setGrafanaCredentials
        elif [ "$service" == "node-red" ]; then
            echo "Setting Credentials for node-RED"
            setNodeRedCredentials
        elif [ "$service" == "portainer" ]; then
            echo "Setting Credential for Portainer"
            setPortainerCredentials
        fi
    done
fi
```

### EDIT

Upon suggestion I tried `${SELECTED_SERVICES[@]}` in the for loop and added an `echo "$service"` which is able to loop through the array however the `if` conditions are not triggered.

Comment: `set -x` is always your friend in this class of issue (with `BASH_XTRACEFD` to set the log destination to somewhere else if you need to keep stderr clean).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the logic in your `askGenerateCredential()` function is not doing what you want it to do.  Currently the entire output of your whiptail command is being added to the array as a single element.  If you want multiple elements split at newlines you should change it to something like this:

```
askGenerateCredential() {
    local message="Set Password for particular Service\n
                Press <SPACEBAR> to Select \n
                Press <Enter> to Skip
                "
    local arglist=()
    
    # Generate a String for Whiptail Checkboxes
     # FORMAT: "<INDEX> <DESCRIPTION> <OFF>"
    for index in "${!availableServices[@]}";
    do
        # Default all Services are NOT-Selected (OFF)
        arglist+=("$index" "${availableServices[$index]}" "OFF")
    done
    readarray -t SELECTED_SERVICES < <("$WHIPTAIL" --title "Available Services within Populo" \
                --notags --separate-output \
                --ok-button Next \
                --nocancel \
                --checklist "$message" "$LINES" "$COLUMNS" $(( LINES - 12 )) \
                -- "${arglist[@]}" \
                3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
}
```

See [4.2 Bash Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins)

---

Also you are calling `SELECTED_SERVICES` as a variable instead of an array.

You need to change:

```
for service in "${SELECTED_SERVICES}"
```

to:

```
for service in "${SELECTED_SERVICES[@]}"
```

As is you will only expand the first element of the array.  However as your code is written `SELECTED_SERVICES` will only ever receive a single element.

See [6.7 Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays)

---

Additionally case would probably be better used instead of the if/elif construct. Something like:

```
case $service in
    influxdb)   echo "Setting Credentials for InfluxDB"; setInfluxDBCredentials;;
    grafana)    echo "Setting Credentials for Grafana"; setGrafanaCredentials;;
    node-red)   echo "Setting Credentials for node-RED"; setNodeRedCredentials;;
    portainer)  echo "Setting Credential for Portainer"; setPortainerCredentials;;
    *)  echo "Error; unknown option: $service" >&2;;
esac
```

Comment: @Shan-Desai: I don't think it actually does.  See my edit.

Comment: @Shan-Desai: case can still be used, you would just add it within the for loop in place of the if/elif construct.  The `*` probably wouldn't be necessary anymore although in this case likely wouldn't hurt